# Different DPI Screen Resolutions (PIXELS)

Tags: android, resolution, dpi

i just wanted to know. i've read about this DPIs and i wandered all of the varieties. since i am new to this, i need some knowledge and i hope someone can help me out. so far i've seen **LDPI, MDPI, HDPI, XHDPI, XXHDPI, XXXHDPI.**

is there any other DPI variety other than this. and what is their respective resolutions ?. like as for qHD = 960 x 540 etc etc. i hope you understand guys, thanks.

please forgive me if my grammar is a little crappy, as english is not my native language

Comment: You are confusing **density** (dpi) and **resolution** (pixels).

Comment: Please read out this link http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: size of images depend on relevent screen resolution in android  suppose you want one image of 100*100 then                                    ldpi 0.75x
mdpi 1.0x
hdpi 1.5x
xhdpi 2.0x
xxhdpi 3.0x

Answer (score 3):

Android supports different screen resolutions

```
ldpi (low) ~120dpi
mdpi (medium) ~160dpi
hdpi (high) ~240dpi
xhdpi (extra-high) ~320dpi
xxhdpi (extra-extra-high) ~480dpi
xxxhdpi (extra-extra-extra-high) ~640dpi
```

1 dpi = 1 design independent pixel

*ldpi*  device have *120* pixels in  *1* inch size.

same for other densities...

we as programmer should use this conversion formulae :

*pixel = dp * (density / 160)*

so 240 dpi hdpi device's 1 dp will have =  1 * (240/160) = 3/2 = 1.5 pixels

and 240 dpi xxhdpi device's 1 dp will have = 1 * (480/160) = 3 pixels

Using this 1.5 and 3 pixels knowledge, programmer can design layouts for different densities

Comment: Please check developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html ->  Range of screens supported